# Website not displaying content properly in IE 11 and perhaps other versions

Tags: html, css

I'm finishing up a web design project that I'm supposed to be presenting today, and I realized I hadn't tried loading it up in Internet Explorer because I'm not a monster and don't use IE.

I was shocked when my website looked like a complete hot mess. Here's what it's looks like and how it's supposed to look:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2IQv.jpg

Since I'm getting no real errors back through validation and it properly loads in literally every other browser, I'm hoping it's some goofy compatibility tag or something.

Here's a link to the whole site uploaded and live:
http://dboards.carlwatkins.com

Help me Stackoverflow... you're my only hope.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Comment: Add a `display:block` to `main` and test it out in IE and see how that looks.

Comment: YOU'RE MY HERO wmeade!

Mind giving me a little insight to why it's required in IE but not other browsers?

Comment: you did not close properly your script tag within conditionnal comment and did not close the comment for the div .fltr Browsers try to correct your coding errors, looks like IE fails to correct you correctly :) ... IT is not the first time i see IE destroying a page just because of comments tag miswritten

Comment: `<!-- [if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://htmlshim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
</scripty>
<! [endif] -->`  scripty ?

Comment: `<!--   <div class="fltr"><img src="img/progress.jpg"></div> 
    <p>
        DorkBoards is Central Ohio's premier map and board makers for miniature gaming. Started in 2015 by a group of friends and gamers,
        the company has quickly become known for it's high quality, handmade maps for use in Malifaux and other miniature based games. Each map
        is custom made with a wide variety of both standard and premium options to make your map as unique as you are.
    </p>
    <br>
    <!-->
` you open a comment unprperly when the previous is not closed

Comment: GCyrillus51: That is an oversight, but that's not what's causing every page within the site to not load properly. Thanks for pointing it out though, I'll be sure to remove all that redundant code from the previous version of the page :)

Adding block display to main resolved the issue on all pages.

Comment: Awesome, glad that helped. Most browsers seem to default the `display` to `block` when it's not declared. If you change `main` to `display:inline` and check it out in Chrome for example, it displays similarly to how IE was displaying your site. So I suspect IE may default to `display:inline`, whereas other modern browsers default to `display:block`.

Comment: `<!-- [if lt IE 9]>` You screw around with IE, and you can expect IE to be screwed. These days I actually code for it first. Lo and behold, it's A) not hard thanks to better tools than Firefox, B) Tends to look the same in other browsers thanks to standardization.